# MainActivity is still clickable when a navigation bar is open

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer

The thing is I am working on an application on Android Studio and it has a navigation bar when I open my navigation bar with a button click or left swipe in the main activity buttons and the scroll would still work while its open
here is my code of navigation bar in the main activity

```
        final DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        final ConstraintLayout navList = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
```

And on button click its

```
if(view.equals(btnmenus))
        {
            DrawerLayout navDrawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            if(!navDrawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) navDrawer.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
            else navDrawer.closeDrawer(Gravity.END);

        }
```

My drawer is created in the activity_main and its gravity is set to left

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer"
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:background="#3c3c3c"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="5dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="24dp">
```

So I don't know when its over the main screen the buttons that are on the main acitivy that are below it that can't even been seen if you click on that area the button would work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, have you tried drawer root xml element clickable?

> `android:clickable="true"`